# How to rebase my branch one commit after another?

Tags: git, rebase

I am not too familiar with rebasing. Currently I have the following situation:

Branch: C1-C2-C3-C4-C5 (develop)
Branch: C1-C2-C6-C7-C8 (feature)

While I could do a 'git rebase develop' from the feature branch, the resulting merge conflicts are too large and difficult to resolve all at once. In reality there are a lot more commits.

Is it possible to rebase one commit after another, until im at the same result as a single rebase?

For example if I'm checked out to the feature branch and do

- git rebase C3 feature
- git rebase C4 feature
- git rebase C5 feature

Would I end up with:
C1-C2-C3-C4-C5-C6-C7-C8 (?)

Is this a good approach, or is there a better way of handling it?

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable

Comment: reasonable approach but the result wont be any different. you will encounter the exact same merge conflicts in the exact same order.. strongly suggest you just merge develop into your branch and then make a single resolution of conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `--i` flag in order to rebase your commits one by one. You will be able to resolve the merge conflicts that arise with every commit, stage the changes and move on by typing `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: It's spelled `-i` or `--interactive`, not `--i`. Passing `-i` also doesn't change anything about the rebase process on its own. Your second sentence is equally true for rebasing without `-i`.